# Update internal DNS server in my organization

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration, namespaces

We have our own internal DNS server inside our network on our domain.  I just changed the nameservers of a bunch of our domain names through our registrar.  Now on my home PC (off the network) the changes were almost immediate.  How ever inside our network the changes are not immediate.  In fact I went into my DNS Manager and I have a few of these domains setup as zones (not all of them) and I notice the records still have the old IP address of the old namespace, and the timestamp is STATIC.  Will I have to manually edit these or can they somehow be automatically updated like everything else once the DNS has propgated on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the values in your DNS servers cache, you'll probably need to flush the cache on the DNS server.

If you have primary zones, these won't be updated automatically.  You'll need to manually change these.

Comment: Ok I was given 3 namespaces for www.mydomain.com.  I put them in my registrar.   Do I need to put each one in my primary zone?  Right now all I have is an IP address.  Thank you!

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more: registrar is network solutions. host is dreamhost.  In my internal dns there are static entries for www.mydomain.com whcih point to the ip address of network solutions (which i'm moving away from).  On network solutions i changed my namepsace to dreamhosts (ns1.dreamhost.com, ns2, etc..). However in my DNS server I can't add FQDN for A records, only IP addresses.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: All you should need to do is double click on the A record for www and change the IP address to the new public IP address.  If your web host and DNS host are dreamhost, you shouldn't need to have a mydomain.com zone in your internal DNS server.  If you were to remove it (assuming you aren't using that domain for anything else) then it should just call the public DNS for the IP just like anyone else would.

Comment: I see. Problem is this domain is also my internal domain name.  I dont' think I can just delete it as a forward lookup zone.  I may jsut have to add aliases to the dreamhost namespaces, or A records for the namespaces ip (but what if they change?)..

Comment: In that case no you can't just remove the domain name.  This is one of the reasons that it is recommended that you don't use your public DNS name and your active directory DNS name.  You'll need to manually change the A records that currently point to the Network Solutions IPs and change them to point to the Dream Host IPs. If DreamHost changes your IPs you'll need to change them in your DNS server.

Comment: No problem, good luck.

Comment: I think I got this worked out. My next domain build will definitely be .local instead of .com (I didn't' originally design this domain).  THANK YOU! Everything appears to be working.

Comment: You can actually rename the Windows domain (I've done it).  It isn't the easiest thing to do, but it can be done over night.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this??  This sounds like a plan. Note i also have a sharepoint and exchange server, if that would make it too difficult.

Comment: Here's the TechNet document on how to rename your Windows domain. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: No need to rename your AD domain.  No need to use made-up top-level domains such as `.local` (a poor idea, as discussed in comments to another answer).  Just [delegate the `www` subdomain](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-split-horizon-common-server-names.html#CorrectionByDelegation).

Comment: If you plan on using some of the newer features such as Direct Access then a non-public DNS name for Active Directory is needed.  While it probably could be setup without, it would be MUCH easier to do it with a non-public DNS name.

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamp is static then I'm going to assume you entered them manually into your DNS server? If so you will need to modify them by hand.

From what I'm seeing in comments, you are making static A records for your domain inside which is the same outside (mydomain.com).

This is a common problem when creating a domain inside your network with a publicly addressable domain, this is why people have domains specified as .local to avoid the problems of using a .com inside their network. It's the same reason there are private ip ranges (192.168.0.0|172.16.0.0|10.0.0.0) so you avoid the problems of routing public ip addresses in and outside your network.

Comment: `.local` has been co-opted by auto-configuration by avahi (aka bonjour).  Configuring .local in DNS can lead to namespace conflicts.  `.lan` and other non-existent top level domain can be used internally.   The upcoming ability to but TLDs may cause problems in the future.  Reserving a  sub-domain like `lan.example.com` for internal addresses may be a better option.